# Optimal MySQL table format

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

In a mysql automotive parts database, which is the optimal table Format?

Scenario 1:

```
Table 1
ID1 | Make | Model | Type

Table 2
ID2 | Part_description | OEM_code

Connection table
ID | ID1 | ID2
```

Scenario 2:

```
Table 1
ID1 | Make

Table 2
ID2 | FK_ID1 | Model

Table 3
ID3 | FK_ID2 | Type

Table 4
ID4 | Part_description | OEM_code

Connection table
ID | ID1 | ID2 | ID3 | ID4
```

In First scenario, the IDs can be used directry for indicating parts, but there are multiple duplicates in make and model columns.

In Second scenario, 3 IDs need to indicate a part and I think that querying would be faster, but I'm not sure about multiple IDS.

What is your opinion?

Comment: With regard to scenario 2, Id2 obviously already incorporates id1 within it, so it's redundant to include id1 again (And likewise for id3). That said, something like this model is probably the right way to go.

Comment: The connection table becomes `Connection table
(ID3 , ID4)`

Comment: Optimal for what?  How will the data be used.  In addition, the two models are different -- imposting different constraints and flexibilities and you haven't explained sufficiently what you want to represent.

Comment: I would label Scenario 2 as "over-normalization".  It leads to clumsy code, inefficiency, etc.  And virtually no benefit.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the data model depends on how you want to use it. Generally it would suffice to have a table per car version:

```
id | car_version
---+--------------------------
1  | BMW 530i 2019
2  | BMW 530e 2019
3  | BMW 540i 2019
4  | BMW 530i 2020
5  | BMW 530e 2020
6  | BMW 530e iPerformance 2020
7  | BMW 540i 2020
```

You would show this list sorted by alphabet to pick a car. With a very long list, however, this can become inconvenient. Hence, if you want to *drill down* to the car version, above table will not be optimal any longer, because you could have typos going unnoticed, like:

```
VMW 530i 2020
```

which would be hidden way down the list. So, you'd want a table for the make to avoid this. You can show a list of makes, pick a make, then show a list of models. And as a model can have several versions, you'll have yet another table, so after picking the model you are shown the versions.

```
table make

make_id | name
--------+-----
1       | BMW


table model

model_id | make_id | name
---------+---------+-----
1        | 1       | 530i
2        | 1       | 530e


table version

version_id | model_id | year
-----------+----------+-----
1          | 1        | 2019
2          | 2        | 2019
3          | 1        | 2020
4          | 2        | 2020
```

Your parts table would then link a part to a car version:

```
table part

part_id | part_number | name
--------+-------------+-------------
1       | 1234567     | battery AXX4
2       | 1238867     | battery AXX5


table part_match

part_id | version_id
--------+-----------
1       | 1
1       | 2
1       | 3
2       | 3
2       | 4
```